# Allow donors to send a note for in honor / in memory donations

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, honoree

Our goal is to have a donation page where the donor enters their details, honoree details, and a note. The note is then sent to the honoree.

In some cases, we would prefer a form that is set up for an individual honoree, so the donor enters only their own details and the note, which is sent to the fixed honoree.

I think the answer is probably a Drupal Webform, but if there are better options or tips on how to do this, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I would be jumping to webform_civicrm - not sure if you are asking for hints on how to do it with w_c (I sensed not) but if you are then pls mention which Drupal version

Comment: It looks pretty obvious how to handle this in webform, so I was more interested in other approaches, if there are any.

Comment: have you wondered whether for your 'fixed honoree' a PCP might get close?? (not saying it does but ....)

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but it does make sense. It is close! Might be able to generalize PCPs to serve for this in core.